# If inner automorphism is identity, are all other automorphisms outer automorphisms in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I do understand the definition of inner automorphism but in the case that where inner automorphism is trivial does that mean that every other automorphism in the ring is outer automorphims? Im asking because outer automotphism is qoutient group  Out(G)=Aut(G)/Inn(G)